# Removing Dupes in a Single Cell, Nested VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I needed to pull multiple vlookup values into a single cell.  To do so I used vba to create a public function called `MULTIVLOOKUP` and it works perfectly resulting in the following values in a single cell:

```
Vendor, Site, ARO, ARO, ARO, Site
```

The formula to get this is: `=MULTIVLOOKUP($J9, $A$2:$A$5000, 4)`

I then used code found here on stackoverflow to remove dupes.  Here is that code which user KazJaw was great in providing:

```
Function UniqueFromCell(rngCell, splitString)

Dim myCol As New Collection
Dim itmCol
Dim i As Long

Dim arrTMP As Variant
arrTMP = Split(rngCell, splitString)

For i = 1 To UBound(arrTMP)
  On Error Resume Next
  myCol.Add arrTMP(i), CStr(arrTMP(i))
  On Error GoTo 0
Next i

Dim result
For Each itmCol In myCol
  result = result & itmCol & splitString
Next

UniqueFromCell = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(splitString))

End Function
```

My resulting formula become:

`=UNIQUEFROMCELL(MULTIVLOOKUP($J9, $A$2:$A$5000, 4), ",").`

It works almost perfect except my result is:  `Site, ARO`

> I lost Vendor!

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(arrTMP)
```

Is the problem. Split is returning a zero-based array not a one-based array. It's safer to write something like `LBound(arrTMP)` instead, to handle both kinds of array properly.

```
For i = LBound(arrTMP) To UBound(arrTMP)
```

You can read up on how arrays work in VBA [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm).